# Having error with Tensorflow Mnist

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I have just started to use Tensorflow and I have done "hello world" with my test.py file. Moving on to next step, I started to do tutorial(https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html).
This is what I have done

> $ git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

and run the file of "fully_connected_feed.py "

> python tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py

I got the error like

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py",
>
> line 27, in
>
> from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
>
> ImportError: No module named examples.tutorials.mnist

so I changed code from

> from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
>
> from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import mnist

to

> import input_data
>
> import mnist

but I got error again.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py", line 27, in
>
> import input_data
>     File
>
> "/Users/naggi/Documents/ML/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/input_data.py", line 29, in
>
> from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist import read_data_sets
>
> ImportError: No module named contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist

Could someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install via pip :

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev

$ sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
I have run the code below 
>sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
but I had another error

> tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I have searched but I can not figure out what is the problem

Comment: @NaggiGoishi What is your platform?

Comment: This is for Linux @NaggiGoishi

Comment: @NaggiGoishi Which Linux? Ubuntu?

Comment: @SungKim: @ NishantSingh, Well... I am using Mac OS (El Capitan). Is this answering your question?

Comment: @NaggiGoishi ".whl is not a supported wheel" I think you can use whl file for mac. Make sure you use the right mac version.

Comment: @SungKim: My mac version is 10.11.4. If you do not mind, can I ask what do you mean with "Make sure you use the right mac version"

Comment: @NaggiGoishi # Mac OS X, CPU only:
$ sudo easy_install --upgrade six
$ sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.8.0-py2-none-any.whl

Comment: @NishantSingh:@SungKim
Thank you! I could download tensorflow and I am going to redo Mnist!

Comment: still got an error: ImportError: No module named contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist

Answer (score 0):

1. update pip to latest version
2. sudo easy_install --upgrade six
3. sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.8.0-py2-none-any.whl

It works for Mac os